# Cant use ImageTk module and Image.fromarray() attribute at the same time

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am making a webcam program with tkinter and pillow. I need to use the Image.fromarray() attribute and the ImageTk. But if i install the version of Pillow with Image.fromarray()i can't use ImageTk and vice versa. When i do this i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\SignIn\dictionary.py", line 66, in <module>
  show_frame()
 File "C:\SignIn\dictionary.py", line 51, in show_frame
  pil = Image.fromarray(frame)
AttributeError: class Image has no attribute 'fromarray'
```

I have tried different versions of Pillow but there doesn't seem to be a version that satisfies both. I can't find any one else having this issue online

Modules:

```
import json
import zbar
import numpy as np
import cv2
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image as y
from PIL import ImageTk
```

Comment: Show us your imports. `fromarray` is a function in the `PIL.Image` module, not a method of PIL's `Image` class.

Comment: I figured it out i relized that i was using Image.fromarray() not y.fromarray() but i still can't use ImageTk